# Calculate mean of last 5 years exclude missing

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like this:

```
Year    Dv1  Dv2  Dv3  Dv4  
2014     1    1    2    5   
2015     3    4    8    8   
2016     2    5    9   11   
2017     4    4    5    9    
2018     2    6    7    9    
2019     2    4    6    .    
2020     1    3    .    .    
2021     3    .    .    .
```

I want to sum the last 5 years for each column with data for a summary line, so ideally I would like my results to look like:

```
Year    Dv1  Dv2  Dv3  Dv4  
2014     1    1    2    5   
2015     3    4    8    8  
2016     2    5    9   11   
2017     4    4    5    9    
2018     2    6    7    9   
2019     2    4    6    .   
2020     1    3    .    .    
2021     3    .    .    .    
Avg5    2.4  4.4   7   8.4
```

Is there a way to do this in SAS? I tried some things with Proc Expand and Lag, but not getting what I want with those.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see the need, but if you must. I assume that Year is a character variable since you want the value 'Avg5' in it. And, I assume you want the result to be a data set, since that is what Proc Expand and the Data Step produces.

```
data have;
input Year $ Dv1 Dv2 Dv3 Dv4;
datalines;
2014 1 1 2 5 
2015 3 4 8 8 
2016 2 5 9 11
2017 4 4 5 9 
2018 2 6 7 9 
2019 2 4 6 . 
2020 1 3 . . 
2021 3 . . . 
;

data want;
   array lag1[0:4] _temporary_;    
   array lag2[0:4] _temporary_;    
   array lag3[0:4] _temporary_;    
   array lag4[0:4] _temporary_;    
    
   do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (z);        
      set have end = z; 
      array dv dv:;

       if Dv1 then lag1[mod(_N_, 5)] = Dv1;
       if Dv2 then lag2[mod(_N_, 5)] = Dv2;
       if Dv3 then lag3[mod(_N_, 5)] = Dv3;
       if Dv4 then lag4[mod(_N_, 5)] = Dv4;           

       output;
   end;

   Year = 'Avg5';
   Dv1 = mean(of lag1[*]);
   Dv2 = mean(of lag2[*]);
   Dv3 = mean(of lag3[*]);
   Dv4 = mean(of lag4[*]);
   output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get statistics on the last N values it to store them into a "wrap around" array.  It would be simpler if you transposed the data.  Then you only need to find the last five non-missing observations for only one variable per year/dv# group.

But here is a solution using multiple arrays.  One to keep track of the number of non-missing values seen and the other to store the last 5 values.

First let's convert your listing into a dataset.

```
data have ;
  input Year $ dv1-dv4 ;
cards;
2014 1 1 2 5 
2015 3 4 8 8 
2016 2 5 9 11 
2017 4 4 5 9 
2018 2 6 7 9 
2019 2 4 6 . 
2020 1 3 . . 
2021 3 . . . 
;
```

Now process the data storing the last5 into the array and copy the input back out.  When you get to the end calculate the means and output the extra observation.

```
data want;
  set have end=eof;
  array next [4] _temporary_;
  array last5 [4,0:4] _temporary_ ;
  array dv dv1-dv4 ;
  do index=1 to dim(dv);
    if not missing(dv[index]) then do;
      next[index]+1;
      last5[index,mod(next[index],5)]=dv[index];
    end;
  end;
  output;
  if eof then do ;
    year='Avg5';
    do index=1 to dim(dv);
      dv[index]=mean(last5[index,0],last5[index,1],last5[index,2],last5[index,3],last5[index,4]);
    end;
    output;
  end;
  drop index;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    Year    dv1    dv2    dv3     dv4

 1     2014    1.0    1.0     2      5.0
 2     2015    3.0    4.0     8      8.0
 3     2016    2.0    5.0     9     11.0
 4     2017    4.0    4.0     5      9.0
 5     2018    2.0    6.0     7      9.0
 6     2019    2.0    4.0     6       .
 7     2020    1.0    3.0     .       .
 8     2021    3.0     .      .       .
 9     Avg5    2.4    4.4     7      8.4
```